# How can I implement "add new item" text in dynamic listbox and change its position on item added?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dynamic, listbox

I have dynamic listbox bound with observable collection and contains textbox to display list property. I want "add new label" as a last item of listbox and click on label turns into textbox which is bound with listbox data template. So visual structure is like this:

Scenario 1: When No item in listbox:

ListBox:

1. Add new Item

Scenario 2: When 3 items in listbox:

ListBox:

1. Item1
2. Item2
3. Item3
4. Add new Item

When user click on add new item, that label should be replaced by textbox and user can add new item in it. And "Add New Item" label moved down one step.

Anyone knows how can I do that in WPF?

My code:

```
 <ListBox Name="ListUrls"   ItemsSource="{Binding . ,Source=ListSourceCollection,BindsDirectlyToSource=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <RadioButton>
                        <WrapPanel>
                        <TextBox Name="TextBoxList" Text="{Binding Path=urlString, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" Focusable="{Binding IsEditing}" FocusableChanged="TextBoxList_FocusableChanged" Background="Transparent" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" Width="150" Foreground="Gray" MouseEnter="TextBoxList_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="TextBoxList_MouseLeave">                
                        </TextBox>
                        </WrapPanel>
                    </RadioButton>

                    <ToggleButton Name="EditButton" Content="Edit" Grid.Column="1" Click="Button_Click" IsChecked="{Binding IsEditing}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0">
                        <ToggleButton.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditing}" Value="False"></Condition>
                                            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True"></Condition>
                                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>

                                        <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                        </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </ToggleButton.Style>
                    </ToggleButton>


                    <Button Content="Delete" Grid.Column="2" Click="Button_Click_1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0">
                        <Button.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="Button">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditing}" Value="False"></Condition>
                                            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True"></Condition>
                                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                        </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Button.Style>
                    </Button>

                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>

        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

    </ListBox>
```

Comment: -1. Please include the relevant code of what you **already** tried.

Comment: @HighCore I added code. I guess code for toggle button and button is irrelevant here.... question is only focused on textbox which is binded to property.

Comment: I would suggest using `CompositeCollection` in your items Source along with defined `DataTemplate` which would represent the `Add new item`. To handle adding new item you can do through your `VM` and then pass the data in the `CommandParameter`. At last just call on your `ObservableCollection` `Add()` method that should do the trick. If you need more info let us know HTH.

Comment: @XAMlMAX If you can have similar code example somewhere or you can give basic idea to implement this, it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a "Static" property in your `ListView` you need:

```
<CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding ObservableCollection}" x:Key="requiredList"/>
```

in your `ListView` you assign `ItemsSource` like so:

```
<ListView.ItemsSource>
<CompositeCollection>
    <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource requiredPeople}}"/>
</CompositeCollection>
</ListView.ItemsSource>
<Button Content="Add new Item" Command="..." ComandParameter="..."/>
```

I can't remember if you need to wrap the button in ListViewItem or not.

Please bare in mind that you will need temporary field on your `VM` to bind it to the DataTemplate.
You will also need `ICommand` on your `VM` this way you can add new Item to your collection when you handle your command.
**NOTE:**
This is from my head I don't guarantee that this will work but it should give you an idea of how to tackle the problem.
**EDIT**
Instead of the `Source` use `Collection` in the `CollectionContainer`.